# explicit default copy constructor -- compile error

Tags: c++

Usually, I tend to use `explicit` keyword in the constructor to avoid implicit conversion.

But when I try implement `Matrix` class, compile error happened in the `operator*()` function, it showed:

`error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Matrix'`, however, when I remove the `explicit` key word in the copy constructor, every thing goes well.

I know what `explicit` means, it means the parameter should be EXACTLY matched, when returning `res` in the `operator*()` function, the copy constructor will be called, I think the parameter is well matched, but why the error happened?

```
class Matrix {
private:
  vector<vector<int>> mat;
  int n;

public:
  explicit Matrix(int n): n(n) {
    this->mat.assign(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
  }

  explicit Matrix(const Matrix& obj) {
    this->n = obj.mat[0].size();
    this->mat = obj.mat;
  }

  Matrix operator*(const Matrix& rhs) {
    Matrix res(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
          res.mat[i][j] += this->mat[i][k] * rhs.mat[k][j];
        }
      }
    }

    return res; // Compiler error here!
  }
};
```

Comment: s/default copy constructor/copy constructor/g

Comment: It happens for the same reason returning `5` would give an error. No implicit conversion from `const Matrix &` to `Matrix` exists. I don't know what that has to do with matching parameters exactly.

Comment: Why exactly do you want an explicit copy constructor?

Comment: "I know what `explicit` means, it means the parameter should be EXACTLY matched" - no it doesn't. It means the constructor can't be used implicitly, which makes an explicit copy constructor rather useless. It makes sense for other single-argument constructors (like your first one), to prevent them being used for implicit conversions.